# Converting X, Y coordinates pixel of screenshot image.png from map to really Long, lat

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, latitude-longitude, pyproj

I need to convert the x,y coordinate of the PNG image from the map into Latitude and Longitude. I took an image from google-map that map image is cut from the part of the city here is a sample image which I have drawn two points on it. I used "pyproj" to convert x/y coordinates to lat/long. But it doesn't give me correct values, for instance, my original long and lat is(59.944321, 30.179938) but when I convert X,Y coordinate to long and lat, I received something like this value (-13.487453788374928, 0.000983113712533505).

How can I convert it to the real value?

The function works correctly I checked it out with the original Long and lat.

Do I need to get extra information from Google Maps when I take a screenshot from the interest region?

I am completely new to this topic and I don't know what information I need to deal with this problem.

[image].

Here I added my script code.

```
import cv2
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import geopy.distance
import pyproj

def lonlat_to_xy(lon, lat):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=29, datum='WGS84')
    xy = pyproj.transform(proj_latlon, proj_xy, lon, lat)

    return xy[0], xy[1]

def xy_to_lonlat(x, y):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=29, datum='WGS84')
    lonlat = pyproj.transform(proj_xy, proj_latlon, x, y)

    return lonlat[0], lonlat[1]

def find_distance(coordinates_from, coordinates_to):

    return geopy.distance.geodesic(coordinates_from, coordinates_to).km

def draw_points(img):

    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    x, y = width // 2, height // 2
    # cv2.circle(img, (x, y), radius=5, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=3)  # center of image

    p1 = (int(x - 80), int(y + 75))
    p2 = (int(x - 108), int(y + 165))

    cv2.circle(img, (p1[0], p1[1]), radius=5, color=(25, 255, 255), thickness=3)
    cv2.circle(img, (p2[0], p2[1]), radius=5, color=(25, 0, 255), thickness=3)

    return img, p1, p2


path1 = r'./dist.png'
img = cv2.imread(path1)

# draw points on the image
img, p1, p2 = draw_points(img)

# extract longitude and longitude from (X,Y) coordinates 
lon1, lat1 = xy_to_lonlat(p1[0], p1[1])  # x-axis is longitude and y-axis lat
lon2, lat2 = xy_to_lonlat(p2[0], p2[1])

# find Distance between two points
distance1 = find_distance((lon1, lat1), (lon2, lat2))
# real lat and lon from googl map the same area.
orig_lon1, orig_lat1 = 59.944321, 30.179938  # p1
orig_lon2,orig_lat2  = 59.95343, 30.18449   # p2
original_distance_on_map = find_distance((orig_lon1, orig_lat1), (orig_lon2, orig_lat2))

print('distance1', distance1)
print('Original_distance_on_map', original_distance_on_map)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Which pyproj version - this (https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/proj.html?highlight=transform#pyproj.Proj.transform) seems to suggest you are giving wrong values to transform??  Also to check whether your code is correct you need a number of sample points in the area and see if they convert correctly.  If they do then all good, however, since you didn't get a value anything like what you expected -  it looks like something is definitely wrong

Comment: Dear Mr R, thank you for replying. Actually, the version of Pyproj is "pyproj 2.2.0". Also, I put the real numbers of my (long and lat) on the code(59.944321, 30.179938 ) and (59.95343, 30.18449), I checked these points with function lanlon_to_xy() and xy_to_latlon(), they show the same value that the original was. thanks in advance

Comment: ok - yeah that's correct for that API ... How do you know where (0,0) is on the imag? Or the X/Y of your coordinates??

Comment: I don't know exactly. I just draw to points on the real google map also you can see on the image and then took a screenshot from the map my image size is (300x200). if it's possible for you to try the code by different images to see what I mean. Tnx

Comment: sorry no I can't .. but one of your lat/long - don't you know where it is on the image (i.e. x,y)?  IF you have both you can adjust the XY - compare what projected gives and work out an offset .. then you should be able to go from image XY to PCS XY to lat lon.

Comment: Ok, I will try to figure it out. just one question more, do I need to have extra information from the Google Map when I take a screenshot from the interest region? like center point or zoom value?